# Intellij startup error due to bootstrap plugin on Mac

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bootstrap-4

After installing a bootstrap plugin from the IntelliJ plugin marketplace, it asks for a reboot. After restarting Intellij, it is not open and showing the following log. I have already tried reinstalling it. I am using the community version 2022.3

````
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.plugin.bootstrap.BootstrapPluginApplicationComponent
            ' [Plugin: nl.jworks.intellij.bootstrap3]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:571)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:382)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.access$registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.registerComponents(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.doInitApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$doInitApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$doInitApplication$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:61)
    at com.p.s.k.p._g.k(_g.java:60)
    at com.p.s.k.p.p6.k(p6.java:113)
    at com.p.s.k.p.pa.p(pa.java:139)
    at com.p.s.k.p.pG.p(pG.java:57)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.kt:13)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$startApplication$7.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:294)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.kt:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.plugin.bootstrap.BootstrapPluginApplicationComponent
             PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Bootstrap 3, id=nl.jworks.intellij.bootstrap3, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/plugins/bootstrap3.jar, version=4.1.1, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=12, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:495)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:374)
    ... 26 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 aarch64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home```
````

Comment: Looks like it is a known problem that wasn't addressed yet https://github.com/bodiam/intellij-bootstrap/issues . To make the IDE work again, please remove the plugin from the [plugins folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#plugins-directory) and restart.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov On this version, the plugin folder is shifted to the Application Package Content in the Application folder. The /Library/Application Support path does not have any JetBrains folder as they mentioned on their website. I have tried reinstalling the IDE but the result is same

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a same issue. That bootstrap plugin has issues. to resolve the startup issue bootsrap3.jar file should be deleted from the installation path which is mentioned in your error log itself.

```
path=~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/plugins/bootstrap3.jar
```

But there is tricky problem in Mac, the above path can't be found in the Mac generally. Generally we find the global Library path when trying to `cd /Library` but Jetbrains directory can't be found in the `Library/Application Support` folder.
There is an user level Library folder which by default hidden in Macbooks.
Path should be like `/Users/{Your User}/Library/Application Support/...`.
This Path can't be found in Finder but you can directly hit the path in terminal using:

```
cd /Users/{Your User}/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/plugins/bootstrap3.jar
```

and delete the bootstrap3.jar then restart the Idea it will open without any issues.